# Do I need an Rss Feed? Where to Start?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

I Have an WebPart That saves News to an List and in this Webpart it show the the news as u see my problem is , if i add more news in the list and then what to show it in this webpart it only shows one new but i want i to to show all the news.
I Think i need an Rss Feed, someone that now were to start?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what version of SharePoint you are using. There is an RSS Feed Web Part available in MOSS 2007 that might meet your need:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/add-rss-feeds-to-your-sharepoint-site-HA010291095.aspx

Also in SharePoint Server 2010:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/view-and-read-rss-feeds-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Unfortunately, these Web Parts are NOT available in the free versions, WSS or SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Hi! Didnt you se my image that i uploaded?